# Why does not SetByteArrayRegion corrupt memory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, java-native-interface, jvm-hotspot

The [`SetByteArrayRegion`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/c9035b8e388b/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l3854) function is implemented as

```
JNI_ENTRY(void, \
jni_Set##Result##ArrayRegion(JNIEnv *env, ElementType##Array array, jsize start, \
             jsize len, const ElementType *buf)) \
  JNIWrapper("Set" XSTR(Result) "ArrayRegion"); \
  DTRACE_PROBE5(hotspot_jni, Set##Result##ArrayRegion__entry, env, array, start, len, buf);\
  DT_VOID_RETURN_MARK(Set##Result##ArrayRegion); \
  typeArrayOop dst = typeArrayOop(JNIHandles::resolve_non_null(array)); \
  if (start < 0 || len < 0 || ((unsigned int)start + (unsigned int)len > (unsigned int)dst->length())) { \
    THROW(vmSymbols::java_lang_ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException()); \
  } else { \
    if (len > 0) { \
      int sc = TypeArrayKlass::cast(dst->klass())->log2_element_size(); \
      memcpy((u_char*) dst->Tag##_at_addr(start), \
             (u_char*) buf, \
             len << sc);    \
    } \
  } \
JNI_END
```

As can be observed it calls `memcpy` on a native pointer to the java heap array: `dst->Tag##_at_addr(start)`. `memcpy` itself is not atomic so I concluded that nothing stops GC from moving the array in the middle of `memcpy` call.

Moreover the array can be moved somwhere right after the `dst->Tag##_at_addr(start)` again causing memory corruption.

By contract, "critical" methods employ the `GC_locker::lock_critical(thread);`.

So why are `SetArrayRegion` methods safe? What did I miss?

Comment: This is implementation dependant. It can disable the GC while copying the array, or it can mark the array as unmovable.

Comment: @MauricePerry Could you please elaborate a bit? Where is that done for `SetArrayRegion`? I looked at `JNIHandles::resolve_non_null` but it simply does the cast to `oop*` and dereferences the pointer with some asserts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, the function is wrapped in [`JNI_ENTRY`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/fba8dbd018a6/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l528) macro, which in turn performs [`ThreadInVMfromNative`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/fba8dbd018a6/src/share/vm/runtime/interfaceSupport.hpp#l537) state transition. This means, a Java thread executing `SetByteArrayRegion` is guaranteed to be in `_thread_in_vm` state.

Non-concurrent compacting collectors can move objects only at the global safepoint. A safepoint implies that all Java thread are either blocked or running native code (`_thread_in_native` state).

So, if a safepoint is requested while `SetByteArrayRegion` is running, JVM will wait until all threads complete current VM operation. Сontrariwise, if `SetByteArrayRegion` is executed while GC is running, the thread will block at state transition until GC completes.